# a.style.display: Value assigned to primitive will be lost

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Consider this JavaScript snippet:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.style.display = "none";
```

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 highlights `a.style.display` and gives this hint:

> Value assigned to primitive will be lost
>
> Checks for improper usage of wrappers for JavaScript primitive types. Also, warning will be produced when property of primitive type is modified, as assigned value will be lost

[image: IntelliJ IDEA hint]

[`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) is not a primitive type, thus the assignment to `display` won't be lost.

[`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is a wrapper type. How am I using it (improperly)?

The code seems to work fine in Chrome and Edge. What's the deal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923424/value-assigned-to-primitive-will-be-lost

Comment: I've seen that question but didn't really understand the comments. Also, I don't have a loop or even a function here.

Comment: Are you inside a function ?

Comment: In my original code, yes, I am inside a function. But as you can see from the screenshot, this even happens if the snippet is the sole content of the file.

Comment: Issue is listed [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/667)

Comment: That's the list of IntelliJ hints which apparently should be implemented in eslint.

Comment: I believe this is a spurious message.  Here is a pretty good explanation of the temporary objects JavaScript uses to wrap primitive types when they are used in an object-like way: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/javascripts-primitive-wrapper-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing improper in your code, IntelliJ's type inference is getting a bit confused (this aspect of JavaScript is particularly confusing).

Its linter sees a string and assumes you will try something like this:

```
var primitive = "september";
primitive.vowels = 3;

primitive.vowels;
// => undefined
```

Which would lead to a 'lost' value.

To further understand this weird part of JavaScript, I recommend Angus Croll's excellent in-depth article [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/).