# Value assigned to primitive will be lost in PhpStorm when setting value of String.locale

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I'm using the internationalization library [l10n.js](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js) and it appears you *cannot* pass a value to the library to tell it what language you want to run translations on as it attempts to get the value from the clients browser; so I have been told if you actually want to *set* the locale you would need to do something like:

```
String.locale = 'en-GB';
```

In my case I am doing:

```
String.locale = $('html').attr('lang');
```

...right at the top of the file.

This works, however in **PhpStorm** I get the warning that:

> Value assigned to this primitive will be lost

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923424/value-assigned-to-primitive-will-be-lost) out and understand why they got the warning, but am unsure in my instance - is it basically just telling me that the current value of `String.locale` will be lost?

Comment: Could you give more context like how and where you set the `String.locale`?

Comment: @Linek Updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a false alarm of the PhpStorm type inference system.

The `String` is not a primitive in JavaScript language. It is safe to assign a value to the property of the `String` here because of the `String` function is an `object`.

I suppose that the key idea of the `Value assigned to this primitive will be lost` could be described with the code:

```
> var primitive = "somestring";
> primitive.someprop = 3;
3
> primitive.someprop; 
undefined
```

In JavaScript there are 5 primitive types: undefined, null, boolean, string and number. Primitives are not objects and they have no properties. If JavaScript detects an attempt to assign a property to a primitive it will indeed coerce the primitive to an object. But this new object has no references and will immediately become fodder for garbage collection. Therefore a value assigned to primitive will be lost. [link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/)

Comment: All makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>PHPStorm warns you about creating objects of `String`. Each of new instance will not contain `locale` variable as it's not declared in `String.prototype`. The code below should explain it.</s>

```js
var index = 1;
function test(value) {
 document.body.innerHTML += index++ + " " + value;
  document.body.innerHTML += "</br>";
}

test(String.locale); // 1 - check if locale exists

String.locale = "locale";
test(String.locale); // 2 - should return "locale"

String.prototype.locale = "other locale";
test(String.locale); // 3 - should strill return "locale"
test(String.prototype.locale); // 4 - should return "other locale"

test("".locale); // 5 - "other locale"
test(String("").locale); // 6 - "other locale"
test((new String("")).locale);  // 7 - "other locale"

String.locale = "locale";
test((new String("")).locale); // 8 - still "other locale", "locale" variable is not used when creating objects from "String" thus it's lost in all instances of this constructor
```

**NOTE:**

It seems PHPStorm warns about those primitives only:

- Number
- String
- Boolean
- null (not Null, null)

It's IDE specific behavior. It doesn't notify about custom objects.

**EDIT**
After some research I understood I was wrong. It seems my answer wasn't related to the PHPStorm warning.

When you create a primitive variable and set it's property like so: `primitive.locale = "en-GB"` and try to access it by `primitive.locale` it will be undefined. That's what the warning is trying to tell you.

What I said about primitives still stand, PHPStorm notifies you only about `Number`, `String`, `Boolean` and `null`.

Check code below:

```js
var someBoolean = true;
someBoolean.locale = "en-GB";
document.body.innerHTML += someBoolean.locale;

document.body.innerHTML += "</br>";

var someString = "test";
someString.locale = "en-GB"
document.body.innerHTML += someString.locale;
```

Comment: Ok oh thanks. However, when I do a `console.log(String.locale)` it outputs the value I set fine, so it's definitely not `undefined`.

Comment: @Brett Because `String` is not a primitive, it's a function. It seems like a false alarm from `PHPStorm`. It is probably a good idea to report it.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now :)

Answer (score 0):

Or, as in my case, you can trigger this error like so:

```
const testObj = {};
testObj.name.first = 'jane';
```

It doesn't like the fact that the 'name' property has yet to be defined before we have started assigning stuff to it.