# Express value assignment after middleware: Value assigned to this primitive will be lost

Tags: node.js, express, intellij-idea, mongoose, async-await

I have in express two route handlers, one is a param callback middleware that executes when a [parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param) is matched, and the second one is executed too with the above parameter on a DELETE method.

The code is as below:

```
const findPlan = async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            let projection = {};
            let plan = await AppPlans
                .findOne({_id: req.params.appPlanID, active: true})
                .select(projection)
                .exec();
            if (!plan) {
                let err = new Error("No plan found");
                err.status = 404;
                return next(err);
            }
            req.plan = plan;
            return next();
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    };

const deletePlan = async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            req.plan.active = false;
            await req.plan.save();
            return res.sendStatus(202);
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    };
```

The above gives me on the part `req.plan.active = false` the warning:

> Value assigned to this primitive will be lost

Previously the warning was not shown while the `findPlan` function's Mongoose query was defined with a callback, as:

```
const findPlan = function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            let projection = {};
            AppPlans
                .findOne({_id: req.params.appPlanID, active: true})
                .select(projection)
                .exec(function (err, plan) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    else if(!plan){
                        let err = new Error("No plan found");
                        err.status = 404;
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    req.plan = plan;
                    return next();
                });
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    };
```

Is there anything wrong, like an edge case, or is it just a false positive as I am seeing other cases of this warning being not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923424/value-assigned-to-primitive-will-be-lost Check this it may help!

Comment: @VenkatShukla Yes, I actually saw that before, but considering the way the bug was shown, since they treated it as a bug, I was expecting in my case to be the opposite, since with the callback I think i have it inside some "wrapper"? While with async/await the "wrapper" is removed so it should have been the callback one with the warning, and the other one, with async/await without it.

Answer (score 0):

When your passing values between middlewares in Express.js you should use `res.locals` to store values as this is the [official documented](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) approach. This could likely be the reason for the warning.

```
const findPlan = async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            let projection = {};
            let plan = await AppPlans
                .findOne({_id: req.params.appPlanID, active: true})
                .select(projection)
                .exec();
            if (!plan) {
                let err = new Error("No plan found");
                err.status = 404;
                return next(err);
            }
            res.locals.plan = plan;
            return next();
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    };

const deletePlan = async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            res.locals.plan.active = false;
            await res.locals.plan.save();
            return res.sendStatus(202);
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You are right about the usage, hadn't actually read about this thing being the official way. 
The warning though still shows, and I also wasn't expecting that would have been the case, considering that the callback approach doesn't show it.